# How to run mongodump command in spawn/exec child process with arguments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, child-process, mongodump

I need to run mongodump command with below arguments

```
    var dbhost = mongoose.connection.host || "127.0.0.1",
                    dbport = mongoose.connection.port,
                    dbname = mongoose.connection.name,
                    dbuser = mongoose.connection.options.user,
                    dbpass = mongoose.connection.options.pass,
                    backupPath = path,
                    date = new Date(),
                    currentDate =  date.toLocaleString(),
                    backupFileName ='DBBACKUP-'+currentDate;
```

how to pass above variables to child process

I've tried with below code

```
var backupDB = spawn('mongodump --host '+dbhost+' --port '+dbport+' --username '+dbuser+' --password '+dbpass+' --db '+dbname+' --archive=backupFileName.gz --gzip');
backupDB.stdout.on('data',function(data){ console.log('stdout: ' + data);
```

it throwed this error

```
error: uncaughtException: spawn mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --username --password --db mydb --archive=backupFileName.gz --gzip ENOENT
```

Comment: Can you not just interpolate the values into the string?

Comment: But really, just read here [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), `spawn()` takes the name of a command, and *an array* of arguments to pass to that command:

```
var backupDB = spawn('mongodump', [
  '--host',     dbhost,
  '--port',     dbport,
  '--username', dbuser,
  '--password', dbpass,
  '--db',       dbname,
  '--archive=backupFileName.gz',
  '--gzip'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this and it works perfectly

```
var backupDB = exec('mongodump --host='+dbhost+' --port='+dbport+' --username='+dbuser+' --password='+dbpass+' --db='+dbname+' --archive='+backupPathDir+'/'+backupFileName+'.gz  --gzip');
            backupDB.stdout.on('data',function(data){
                console.log('stdout: ' + data);// process output will be displayed here
            });
```